# jQuery UI Sortable - Error: cannot call methods on sortable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'serialize'

Tags: jquery, html, serialization, jquery-ui-sortable

How to .sortable( "serialize" ) only #sortable1?

Every time on #sortable1 Update I get error:

> Error: cannot call methods on sortable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'serialize'

jQuery code

```
$( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
  connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
  update: function(event, ui){
    var sorted = $("#sortable1").sortable( "serialize" );
    console.log( sorted );
  }
}).disableSelection();
```

HTML code

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
                      <div class="ui-state-default" id="item_1">Item 1</div>
                      <div class="ui-state-default" id="item_2">Item 2</div>
                      <div class="ui-state-default" id="item_3">Item 3</div>
                      <div class="ui-state-default" id="item_4">Item 4</div>
                      <div class="ui-state-default" id="item_5">Item 5</div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
                  <div class="ui-state-highlight" id="item_11">Item 1</div>
                  <div class="ui-state-highlight" id="item_22">Item 2</div>
                  <div class="ui-state-highlight" id="item_33">Item 3</div>
                  <div class="ui-state-highlight" id="item_44">Item 4</div>
                  <div class="ui-state-highlight" id="item_55">Item 5</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by every time on #sortable1 update you get the error? Also the javascript you have included above, where are you calling it from, $(document).ready() ?

Comment: Yes I calling it from $(document).ready(), an every time I try to sort it return this error - Error: cannot call methods on sortable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'serialize'

Answer (score 0):

I found a way out for myself and everything works as I needed, but it is too long script, so if you know how to optimize this I will be very thankful

jQuery code

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#sortable2" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        tolerance: 'pointer'
    });
    $( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
      update: function(event, ui){
        var oi = [];
        var sorted = $( '#sortable1 > div' ).each( function( index, el ) {
            oi.push( { id: index , value: $( this ).data('order') } );
        });
        console.log( oi );
      }
    }).disableSelection();
  });
</script>
```

HTML code

```
<div id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <div class="ui-state-default" data-order="item_1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="ui-state-default" data-order="item_2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="ui-state-default" data-order="item_3">Item 3</div>
  <div class="ui-state-default" data-order="item_4">Item 4</div>
  <div class="ui-state-default" data-order="item_5">Item 5</div>
</div>

<div id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <div class="ui-state-highlight" data-order="item_11">Item 1</div>
  <div class="ui-state-highlight" data-order="item_22">Item 2</div>
  <div class="ui-state-highlight" data-order="item_33">Item 3</div>
  <div class="ui-state-highlight" data-order="item_44">Item 4</div>
  <div class="ui-state-highlight" data-order="item_55">Item 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to define the sortable holder as a variable and use that variable inside the sortable function.

Like this:

```
var sortable_list = $('#sortable1');

sortable_list.sortable({
  ...
  update: function(event, ui){
    var order = sortable_list.sortable('serialize');
    console.log(order);
  }
});
```